# Downgrading from Java 7 to Java 6

Tags: java, netbeans, java-7, java-6

For whatever reason I had to change pc's as a result of the change I now have to use Java 6 (the final update) Instead of java 7. When importing my existing project to Java 6 I get the following error in my auto generated code that was generated by Netbeans and is not modifiable

```
cannot find symbol

symbol: variable Type

location: class Window

    frame.setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP); //Type is underlined
```

The output for the error is as follows:

```
javac: invalid target release: 1.7
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
C:\Users\Adminstrator\Downloads\NetBeansProjects\NetBeansProjects\Pat0.3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:915: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Adminstrator\Downloads\NetBeansProjects\NetBeansProjects\Pat0.3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

What does this do? Is it necessary, would deleting that the component help? Which component is it, is there a quick fix?

Comment: Why don't you simply install Java 7 then? You're administrator, you should be able to. Also: Java 6 is approach its end of life.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Well I did have Java 7 then my teacher said that he would not accept Java 7.3 so I tried installing java 7.2(his copy) and the install failed and all the versions of java i had broke so after "cleaning up java 6 was the only update that worked also I have a limited bandwidth

Comment: Actually i used the other pc because of the messed up java builds

Comment: There is no "Java 7.3" or "Java 7.2" so I don't know what you're talking about. There's only "Java 7" (with updates 1 to 40 (with some holes), but those don't change the language in any way). You might be talking about Netbeans versions, are you?

Comment: open netbeans and change project plattform and put java 6.

Comment: not sure as I am using Eclipse, but in eclipse you can change the execution environment by installing java in separate directory and then pointing to it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake Netbeans 7.3 not Java 7.3

Comment: @Ayvadia: which version of Netbeans you use to write your code should not matter, as long as you use a Java version that's compatible with your teachers (which you seem to do) and are not using the Netbeans platform libraries (pretty unlikely).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Would using DB Apache mean I'm using  The Netbeans platform libraries??

Comment: "DB Apache"? There's no such thing. Are you talking about JavaDB or Apache Derby? In both cases: no, it doesn't. JavaDB is provided with the JDK (but not the JRE) and Apache Derby is a open source project that's independent of both the JDK and Netbeans (and on which JavaDB is based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build.xml specifies the `target="1.7"` flag to javac, which java 6 doesn't know how to interpret.  Changing it to 1.6 will technically get past that error.

However, the enum `Window.Type` was added in Java 7, so you simply can't expect changing the target to work; your project's source uses Java 7 features.  I'm sure that's not the only one.

Your options are therefore to methodically go through and remove/replace all Java 7 code (likely introducing some bugs) or just to.. install Java 7.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion to change the xml file target helped I also Deleted some unused database persistence files and it ran perfectly

Comment: Also what does `Window.Type` do ??

Answer (score 0):

There is somewhere in your project a setting for the java compiler that tells it to generate classes for jre7. `javac` from `jdk6` cannot generate classes for that version, hence the error. So you should look into the properties of your project and set up `javac` to generate classes for `jr6`. You might also have fix some of your non-generated code if for example you have used features that came with java 7 such as diamond operator or multy catch block etc.

Also the javadoc for [Window.Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.Type.html) states it is available only since 1.7. You might want to re-generate that code or better yet just install `jdk7`.